# laravel not loading env if in the IF clause, even though the condition is true;

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

here's my weird code added in bootstrap/app.php:

```
$host = $SERVER['HTTPHOST'] == 'test.local:8000';
var_dump($host);
if ($host) {
    var_dump($host);
    $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
}
```

And what is happening:

$host is always true when I'm trying to get the url above. I see two vardumps (true, true), but the .env is not loading. (the default one is)

BUT if I change it to if(true), it suddenly works. If I put it outside of the if, it also works. Why is this happening? That seems completely illogical.

Comment: `$SERVER['HTTPHOST']` do you mean `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`?

Comment: There are, incidentally, better ways of determining the current environment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#determining-the-current-environment

Comment: the problem is I don't want to read the environment form env. as I got two of them and I want to read them  depending on which url I'm going to for Selenium testing purposes

Comment: I guess you just need simple `if ($SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'test.local:8000') {
    $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
}`

Comment: @Alex - exactly, and that's what is nor working, the rest of the code is just to show that it's getting inside the if clause

Comment: so just do `else { die($SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); }` to check what is there

Comment: `$_SERVER`... Note the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Let's remind some php lessons.
To check either a variable is empty or not, you can do

```
if($var){}
```

if the variable has a value, this will return true, if not it will return false.

In your case, you assign a value to the $host variable when you do `$host = $SERVER['HTTPHOST'] == 'test.local:8000';`. So the if always return true.

What you can do is :

```
if ($host == "test.local:8000") {
     var_dump($host);
     $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
}else{
     //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: when he does `if($host)` he is just checking if the $host variable has a value, not if this equals to "test.local:8000"

So by doing `if ($host == "test.local:8000")` it solves the problem... i guess